# Display posts between two particular dates

Tags: query

I have this code for display posts between two particular dates:

```
$s = '2011-10-23';
$e = '2011-11-17';

function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= ' AND post_date >= $s AND post_date <= $e';
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
```

But that's not work until change to this:

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= ' AND post_date >= '2011-10-23' AND post_date <= '2011-11-17'';
    return $where;
  }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
query_posts($query_string);
```

What's wrong in first code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because the SQL statement needs the dates inside the quotation marks. Try

```
$where .= " AND post_date >= '$s' AND post_date <= '$e'";
```

That should work, otherwise, try

```
$where .= " AND post_date >= '".$s."' AND post_date <= '".$e."'";
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried these codes but both not work. I can't understand why?

Comment: mmm odd. maybe try var_dumping the where string and use wp_die to see whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334678

```
$GLOBALS['start_date'] = date('Y-m-d', ($startdate);
$GLOBALS['end_date'] = date('Y-m-d', ($enddate);

function post_between_date($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($GLOBALS['start_date'])) . "' AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($GLOBALS['end_date'])) . "'";
    return $where;
  }
```